# How can iterate over and modify this Arraylist?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an arrayList which I am sharing between two threads and I am trying to iterate over and modify the list at the same time. I don't want to use the iterator's method, and I have also used the synchronized list but it still gives `concurrentmodificationexception`.

code is as follows :

```
public class testing {
  public static void main(String args[]){

  ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<String> sal=Collections.synchronizedList(al);
   String names[] = {"amol","Robin","vikas","shanu","mahesh"};
  for(String x :names){
       al.add(x);
  }      

  Thread t1 = new Thread(new SyncArrayList(sal));
  Thread t2 = new Thread(new SyncArrayList(sal));    
  t1.setName("T1");
  t2.setName("T2");
  t1.start();
  t2.start();

  }   
}

class SyncArrayList implements Runnable
{
 List<String> unsync ;

SyncArrayList(List<String> l){
   this.unsync = l;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    displayUnsyncList();
    addNames();
  }

void displayUnsyncList(){
   synchronized(this){ 
   ListIterator<String> itr = unsync.listIterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()){
      String x = itr.next();
      System.out.println("Thread " +Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is displaying name : "+x);
   } 
  }
 }

void addNames(){
    unsync.add("preet");
   } 

}
```

Comment: This code should throw a `NullPointerException` on the line `List<String> unsync = Collections.synchronizedList(unsyn);`, since `unsyn` is null.

Comment: i am unable to edit my question ..seems to be some bug consider    `List<String> unsync` as the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) for `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` explains what you need to do:

```
   void displayUnsyncList() {
       synchronized (unsync) {
       ListIterator<String> itr = unsync.listIterator();
       while (itr.hasNext()) {
           String x = itr.next();
           System.out.println("Thread " + 
                              Thread.currentThread().getName() + 
                              " is displaying name : " + x);
       } 
   }
```

In short, your code was synchronizing on the wrong object.

Answer (score 2):

In multithreaded environment you should consider using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` which doesn't produce `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 0):

The iterator you are using is fail-fast iterator.Fail-fast iterator read internal data structure directly . The internal data structure should not be modified while iterating through the collection.

You should use Fail-safe iterator when one or more thread is iterating over the collection, in between, one thread changes the structure of the collection.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> sal = Collections.synchronizedList(al);
    String names[] = { "amol", "Robin", "vikas", "shanu", "mahesh" };
    for (String x : names) {
        al.add(x);
    }

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new SyncArrayList(sal));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new SyncArrayList(sal));
    t1.setName("T1");
    t2.setName("T2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}
```

}

class SyncArrayList implements Runnable {
    List unsyn;

```
// List<String> unsync = Collections.synchronizedList(unsyn);

SyncArrayList(List<String> l) {
    this.unsyn = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(l);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    displayUnsyncList();
    addNames();
}

void displayUnsyncList() {
    synchronized (this) {
        Iterator<String> it = unsyn.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is displaying name : " + it.next());
        }
    }
}

void addNames() {
    unsyn.add("preet");
}
```